# Code to visit multiple web pages using php

Tags: php, mysql

Let me explain the scenario:
I have a table with around 1 million records. Records are hyperlinks of some remote webpages. I need to create a php page say work.php which will take each link from the table and visit those links using commands like file_get_contents and send the response to one email id. I need the best way to code work.php.

I tried retreiving the entire links from db and parsing each row using a while loop. inside the while loop i will use file_get_contents to fetch response and then send mail. it is showing timeout as there are million records.

Please give me the best optimized code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could easily make the script not time out, but where you will run into larger issues is sending requests to 1 million websites, and sending out 1 million emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multithread it and don't use the web to trigger it:**

1. **Run this using PHP CLI** so that you don't need to kept making web
   requests though apache to run the
   script. This will speed things up
   dramatically. This should also get around the timeouts.
2. **Track process state in the db.** Add a flag (char(1)) to the table to indicate the processing state. i.e. null,P,S,F,E for Processing,Started,Failed,Error.
3. When you request a set of url's to process, mark them as 'P' AND request only those that are not marked 'P' (null). Now you can run multiple copies of the same script at once and each will grab different url's to process.
4. During processing mark the url with the other flags when those events occur like and Error or you Start fetching it or Finish processing.

Your typical home box should be able to run several instances of this concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a database table with all the addresses you inted to crawl, and their status.

In your script, search the first record that is marked unprocessed, and process it; after a successful crawl, send the E-Mail, mark the record as finished, and move on to the next record.

Do only a small number of records per request.

If a request times out repeatedly, your script will fail repeatedly. In that case, mark it as broken in your table (doing this adds a bit of complication but is probably necessary. What you will need to do here is to record when you *start* crawling a site, and when it's finished. If there's multiple starts, but no finish, there is a problem with the URL).

Use a header redirect, or a `refresh` meta tag, or a cron job to call the same script repeatedly.

Do this until there are no more unprocessed records in the table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try this.

Comment: If you run multiple crawler threads then you should consider keeping a table of hosts and the last crawl datetime. This way you can prevent hammering hosts with multiple requests each second, and instead spread the load across other hosts that need crawling too. It's also polite to read `/robots.txt` and adhere to the rules defined in it - your hosts table is a good place to keep robots.txt rules.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of your code so the script does not timeout.

Comment: Be sure to log all the emails sent. So write to a log file the id of the database row and a message "$row_id: email sent to $email_address" So if the script fails, you can resume where it failed off at.